# React Native can't connect devices

Tags: android, react-native

when I execute `react-native run-android`,it shows errors like below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This **file access** problem, you can do this as below.

For example my app folder name is **RNapp**

Now open terminal and enter

```
chmod 777 -R RNapp
```

[image]

To verify all changes done or not
[image]

If all name become **green** then all changes done.

Now you can run your react-native app.